# Auto scroll down EditText

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext

I have an Activity that consist in 3 buttons and a EditText, where I add (with EditText.append(String)) some text when the buttons are pressed... The problem is that i couldn't find the way to show the last text lines when they reach the lower limit of the EditText..

Sometimes it works, and the text go up as i add more text lines, but for example, when i touch the screen and move the EditText, it stays there..

The only "solution" that i found was the "scroller", but i don't understand how it works. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really the answer to the question, but for the ones that maybe have the same question as me:

I finally put a `TextView` in a `ScrollView`, and used the `fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` functionality of the ScrollView.. This way i could see the end of the TextView.

I could do this because i didn't need to edit the text added.

Hope it helps.